# Validating the Recaptcha plugin manually

Tags: asp.net, captcha, recaptcha

in my Register form I'm using NHibernate & NHibernate validator (rather than asp:requiredfield validators e.t.c I've put in my Recaptcha plugin:

```
<recaptcha:RecaptchaControl ID="Reg_Recaptcha" PublicKey="x " PrivateKey="y" runat="server" />
```

And i've written this code in my PageHandler to hopefully try figure out if the Recaptcha was valid or not so I can integrate into my validator (rather than calling Page.IsValid. Will this work?

```
Reg_Recaptcha.Validate();
Boolean isRecaptchaValid = RecaptchaResponse.Valid.IsValid;
```

Comment: This is always returning true...

Answer (score 2):

You should do the following:

```
Reg_Recaptcha.Validate();
Boolean isRecaptchaValid = Reg_Recaptcha.IsValid;
```

Comment: That's always returning true.